# How To Stop Data From Getting Deleted On AWS Code Pipeline Having a Laravel Application

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline

I have an elastic beanstalk environment set with code pipeline to my repository which is a Laravel site.

When I push a new change to the master branch it gets changed in the ec2, **AND DELETES ALL DATA IN STORAGE.**

I can't find a similar question online, so any ideas on how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elastic Beanstalk runs on instances that don't persist data between redeployments by default. You need to re-design app to use one of the available options if you really need stable local storage.

Take a look at **Persistent storage** section in the doc below.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts.concepts.design.html